# How to write to Azure Event Grid Topic in Azure Function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-eventhub, azure-eventgrid

I noticed that, all of the sudden, Topics are no longer available as part of Service Bus.  Is it possible to write a message to an Event Grid Topic within an Azure Function?

Comment: have a look at this MSDN document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/post-to-custom-topic

Answer (score 3):

The following code snippet is an example of the using an azure function for pushing a telemetry stream to the eventing model:

[image]

```
#r "Microsoft.ServiceBus"
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"


using System.Configuration;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

// reusable client proxy
static HttpClient client = HttpClientHelper.Client(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TopicEndpointEventGrid"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["aeg-sas-key"]);

// AF
public static async Task Run(EventData ed, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info($"C# Event Hub trigger function processed a message:{ed.SequenceNumber}"); 
    //foreach(var prop in ed.SystemProperties)
    //   log.Info($"{prop.Key} = {prop.Value}");

    // fire EventGrid Custom Topic
    var egevent = new 
    {
        Id = ed.SequenceNumber.ToString(),
        Subject = $"/iothub/events/{ed.SystemProperties["iothub-message-source"] ?? "?"}/{ed.SystemProperties["iothub-connection-device-id"] ?? "?"}",
        EventType = "telemetryDataInserted",
        EventTime = ed.EnqueuedTimeUtc,
        Data = new
        {
            sysproperties = ed.SystemProperties,
            properties = ed.Properties,
            body = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ed.GetBytes()))
        }
    };
    await client.PostAsJsonAsync("", new[] { egevent });  
}

// helper
class HttpClientHelper
{
    public static HttpClient Client(string address, string key)
    {      
        var client = new HttpClient() { BaseAddress = new Uri(address) };
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("aeg-sas-key", key);
        return client;      
    }
}
```

the function.json:

```
    {
      "bindings": [
       {
         "type": "eventHubTrigger",
         "name": "ed",
         "direction": "in",
         "path": "myIoTHubName",
         "connection": "connectionstringIOTHUB",
         "consumerGroup": "eventing",
         "cardinality": "many"
        }
      ],
      "disabled": false
    }
```

Note, that the payload for the AEG Custom Topic is depended from its *inputSchema* property. Basically, current AEG version (included also preview) allows to declare an input schema from the following selection:

- EventGridSchema (default schema)
- CloudEventV01Schema
- CustomEventSchema (still in the preview)

more details can be found:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/input-mappings
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/cloudevents-schema

Comment: I was looking at the EventTime = ed.EnqueuedTimeUtc specifically as I am looking in a way to publish events that need to be processed at a later date, does it work in a similar way as BrokeredMessage.EnqueuedTimeUtc in servicebus which means that the message will be pushed to the topic at the specified date? What I want to achieve is published events to a subscription and then have a logicaapp that will consume these events but several hours or days after the event is published.

Comment: @Spyros I do recommend to create an "iot cold path stream pipeline" such as a storing a device telemetry data to the blob storage for their post processing by Azure Stream Analytics (ASA) job. You can start/stop the ASA job based on your business requirements. Note, that the cost of the ASA job is only by its running time.

Comment: i dont believe this is correct, your `HttpClientHelper` is not safe for multiple consumers

Answer (score 2):

Here is the way to connect to Azure event grid topic in Azure function via Visual Studio code.
NOTE: I didn't have to add any function.json file.

Since Topic is just like an API with URL create an HTTP client pointing to your event data grid topic's URL add the topic's Access key to the HTTP client header.

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient() { 
   BaseAddress = new Uri(<YOUR_TOPIC_URL>) 
};
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("aeg-sas-key", "<YOUR_TOPIC_KEY>");

var egevent = new
{
   Id = 1234,
   Subject = "SendEmail",
   EventType = "SendEmail",
   EventTime = DateTime.UtcNow,
   Data = <YOUR_MESSAGE>(Could be anything and object or data literals)
};
var x = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("", new[] { egevent });
log.LogInformation(x.ReasonPhrase);
```

Hopefully, this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this easily using the [Azure Event Grid Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.EventGrid/):

```
var failedEvent = new EventGridEvent()
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
            Subject = "create-tenant-failed",
            EventType = "create-tenant-failed",
            EventTime = DateTime.UtcNow,
            Data = reason,
            DataVersion = "1.0"
        };

        var topicHostname = new Uri(FailedEventTopicUrl).Host;
        var topicCredentials = new TopicCredentials("my-access-token-from-azure-portal");
        var client = new EventGridClient(topicCredentials);

        await client.PublishEventsAsync(topicHostname, new List<EventGridEvent>() { failedEvent });
```